# How do I configure an existing website or create a new one in WiX?

Tags: iis, wix, installation

I'm creating a wix installer to install multiple web applications, I give the user the option to select an existing website or create a new one. So far, I have implemented the user interface and queried the IIS for the existing websites, but the problem is that I don't know how to configure these two options. I tried using conditional components where I check for a property I set in a custom action but the issue with this scenario is that I end up placing the website element inside a component which I don't want to do in case the user chose an existing website(to avoid it from getting deleted on uninstall)..I found solutions on the web for installing to an existing website or creating a new one but never the both..Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create Custom action for that and set the result of it to wix property.

```
string result ;
session["RESULT"] = result;
```

then in your wxs :

```
  <Custom Action="InstallWebsite" After='InstallFinalize'>NOT Install AND  (<![CDATA[RESULT<>"Existing"]]>)</Custom>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create Custom action for that and set the result of it to wix property.

```
string result ;
session["RESULT"] = result;
```

then in your wxs :